# MS Access - Auto-Update Data Type After Import

Tags: automation, microsoft-access

I am looking to automatically update the data type of numerous fields in MS Access once I have imported some Excel data into the database.

Almost all fields are set to `Text` fields, and this would clearly affect any queries which rely on `date` data in order to run accurately.

An example would be that a couple of the "Due Date" fields' data types are set to `text` post-import, whereas I require them to be set to `date`; I am able to update each data type manually, but would like to know if it is possible to automate this process to save time as I will be regularly importing data into this database.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you considered creating a new table with the proper data types and then appending the text and other fields to the new table? Quick and no coding other than field transformations where you think the implicit type conversion will mangle your data.

Comment: @chuff I have considered this, yes, but was hoping to achieve a more "automated" approach to it with minimal user involvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this myself and will provide the best explanation that I can:

It is/was a very specific issue which relates/related to the data within my spreadsheet; there was an issue some time ago which involved the first row / field headers not being applied correctly, resulting in numerically-incrementing field names in my database.  After some research, I learned a way to resolve this, which then resulted in the problem that I address you with.  Now, I have discarded the previous resolution and have made many small adjustments to my spreadsheet and all appears to be well again.

Apologies for not being able to provide a more informative explanation; I'm sure that you can all appreciate that this is a problem that is specific to me on an individual level and that, if I were to provide a more detailed explanation, it would not make sense without any prior knowledge of the context/background to support it.

Many thanks for your suggestions - all useful contributions have been duly up-voted.

Comment: To summarize this for Googlers: MS Access pulls the column data type from the source input IF its an Excel file and will overwrite Access column types  with their corresponding types from Excel. So either synchronize them in Excel or use a CSV/TXT import file where no data types can be stored in.

Answer (score 1):

Open the table in Design View and change the data type. This will change field in the table, and subsequently all the records stored there.

Keep in mind the format you choose in properties of the field may cause display issues depending on the current format of the data. If the data was consistent when imported, and in the format you need, it should be OK.

Comment: Will these (the data types) remain in place when I next import the data and overwrite the table?  The reason I ask is because this is what I have been doing up until now and it still sets all data types to `text` post-import.

Comment: The data type is a table property. A text import simply places the data into the fields and can not change the table properties. Of course, make sure you backup the database before.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this but my question relates to whether or not the data types will remain in tact once I have imported an updated version of the data (which is in `.xls` format).  I have just tested it out - I have set the data types, saved the changes, and imported the data once again, overwriting the current table - and it "reverted" back to `text` fields once again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that I wrote to change the field size of CSV data that I had to import as all text fields. The code gets the field information from a table of fields, sizes and types I created, and easily modified to via changes to that table.

```
Sub AlterFieldStructure()

' this procedure changes the field size and field types (both text and number fields)
' in the "Rebuild Copy of Grade YYYY"  tables

Dim db As Database
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection

Dim rs_fields As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs_yrtable As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim SQL As String
Dim fieldlist As String

Dim yr As Variant
Dim yrArr As Variant
Dim fld As Variant
Dim fldArr()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim ErrMsg As String

On Error GoTo Err
Set db = CurrentDb
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

' get list of fields to query the "Copy from Grade YYYY" tables
SQL = "SELECT FieldName, DataType, FieldSize  FROM GradeTableFields;"
rs_fields.Open SQL, cn
rs_fields.MoveFirst

i = 1
' Array for field name, datatype, and size
Do Until rs_fields.EOF = True
    If rs_fields!FieldName <> "ID" Then
        ReDim Preserve fldArr(1 To 3, 1 To i)
        fldArr(1, i) = rs_fields!FieldName
        fldArr(2, i) = rs_fields!DataType
        fldArr(3, i) = rs_fields!FieldSize
        fieldlist = fieldlist & rs_fields!FieldName & ", "
        i = i + 1
    End If
    rs_fields.MoveNext
Loop
j = i - 1
rs_fields.Close
Set rs_fields = Nothing
fieldlist = Left(fieldlist, Len(fieldlist) - 2)
yrArr = Array(2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012)
For Each yr In yrArr
    ' for each field in field array
    For i = 1 To j
        SQL = "ALTER TABLE [Rebuild Copy of Grade " & yr & "] ALTER COLUMN " & _
               "[" & fldArr(1, i) & "] "
        If fldArr(2, i) = "Text" Then
            SQL = SQL & "Text(" & fldArr(3, i) & ");"
        ElseIf fldArr(2, i) = "Number" Then
            SQL = SQL & fldArr(3, i) & ";"
        Else
            MsgBox "DataType for " & fldArr(1, i) & " is not Text or Number", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Debug.Print SQL
        db.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError
    Next i
Next yr
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

Exit Sub
Err:
ErrMsg = "Error: " & Err.Number & "  " & "  " & Err.Description
Debug.Print ErrMsg
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```